How to make COUNT(*) get executed quickly on a huge dataset?
I have the following query:
select count(*) as aggregate from users where date(created_at) < '2024-04-01';

It returns 2337355 which is a correct number. But it takes over 1.5 secs to be executed. Any idea how can I make it more optimal and faster?

Noted that I have an idex on users(created_at, type).
Also tried removing date() function like where created_at < '2024-04-01'; but still slow.

Did you test setting an index only on created_at? What storage engine does your table use? Did you consider saving the date part of created_at in a separate, indexed column like created_at_dt?

@Psi the engine is innodb

What happens when you remove the call to the date-function? Just like where created_at < '2024-04-01'?

@Psi https://i.sstatic.net/8Mxn4KKT.png

Ok, and where created_at < '2024-04-01 00:00:00'?

Try using a field name in COUNT that is not nullable. For instance, SELECT COUNT(id) and create an index that includes both, the created_at field as well as the not nullable field (in that order).

@Psi Same result&performance

I don't think indexes hold counts. So it still has to loop through all the index entries before the boundary to count the rows. The index just means it doesn't have to loop through the entire table, just the ones before that date.

Use COUNT(*) rather than COUNT(columnname) unless you need it to check for null values.

Then maybe create a generated column and put an index only on top of that column

@JuanR Nothing changed in the performance

@MartinAJ I added some more notes to my comment. Please read again.

@Barmar that's not entirely correct: If an index exists and can fully be used, it knows its index position = count of rows

@Psi EXPLAIN says it's using the created_at index, so that doesn't seem to be true.

There is very little you can do beyond what you have already done. The index is being used correctly. The only thing I can think of is to get faster disks and/or more RAM. It's over 1m rows, you do need good hardware.

Put the explain output in the question, preferably as formatted text.

@Barmar the index is used, but it's only used partially, because there is another column involved. It has to skip over all those entries

How exactly are you measuring the time? And created_at is a date, right?

@Psi The prefix of an index is also a prefix by itself. It doesn't need to skip anything, because they're subsumed.

@Psi Unless the type column is very wide it's unlikely to make much difference. The overhead of a single row is likely to be at least as much if not more.

@Barmar that is true, however, you then have to iterate through all those subsums (add them up) rather than just extracting your sum from the index position

@SalmanA That query gets throwed inside mysql slow query log file and shows the spent time there

If 1.5 secs seem too much for counting more than 2 million rows from disk, you may want to look for different hardware or an in-memory database system instead.

@Psi I don't see how indexes could possibly store a position without needing a whole lot of writes on insert.  Do you have a link to something talking about use of the index position?  Also note that innodb now implicitly adds the pk to the indexed column, so each index entry will have the date, type, and pk

@MartinAJ always show show create table yourtablename output (as text, not an image) when asking performance/optimization questions.   All the answers and comments here are making a few assumptions, and however reasonable those assumptions are, the table schema will immediately prove or disprove them

COUNT() queries tend to more expensive than one might think. They're about as expensive than any other query that examines millions of rows.
Some people assume because COUNT() returns a single integer result, that's quite small, so the query must be quicker than fetching all the data. But that's not the way it works.
The cost of the query is roughly proportional to the number of rows examined, not the size of the result.
To count rows, InnoDB has to examine each row, because of MVCC. Using an index helps to reduce the number of examined rows, but that could still require examining millions of rows.
So it's pretty much the same in performance cost as a query that reads the same number of rows for some other purpose. It's quicker to pass a single integer back to the client than returning millions of rows, of course, but network transfer speed isn't the bottleneck here.
The workarounds to make your query faster include:

Cache the result of the costly query, so you don't have to run it as often.

Cache partial results, such as daily counts, then sum up these counts for some date range you're interested in. That involves examining fewer rows (e.g. one row per day), so it should be much faster.

Get faster server hardware, and more RAM for the buffer pool. It may still have to examine millions of rows, but to the extent that it does this faster on a more powerful server, it will give you the result faster. It's unlikely to improve performance by orders of magnitude, but it may at least give you a percentage improvement.



Does it have to look at each row in the table? Or the index (since all required information is there)? The index should be much smaller (4mb for a million dates)

@SalmanA, Either way, it has to examine a large number of entries. The important part is the transaction metadata, so it can determine if a given index entry is visible in the caller's transaction snapshot. InnoDB does include this info in the index (otherwise index-only queries wouldn't work), but it still has to check these entries one by one, and that's where the performance cost goes.

@SalmanA its about the number of rows, not the size of rows. And the index will have just as many rows as the table does.

I'm guessing an index on a generated created_at_date column might noticably speed this up; worth mentioning as another workaround.

@JasonCoyne how much actual data needs to be read is a factor, and that depends on the index row size

@ysth The OP already tried to change the expression so it was referencing created_at, which should use the index. That was still too slow for them.

@jason how can it not be about size of rows? Ever heard about covering indexes?

@SalmanA because he isn't selecting any columns, just counting rows. Therefore the width of the table is irrelevant

@jason not the width of table... It is whether to scan the table (could be 1gb) or the index (could be 10mb).

If possible, NEVER use a function in the WHERE on a field. Then MySQL has to read every line, call the function and can only then compare with the VALUE. This means that this will ALWAYS be a FULL TABLE SCAN and therefore cannot use an INDEX.
It could be more sensible, for example:
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2024-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2024-04-01 23:59:59';

to use

That's a good replacement for =, but not <.

it was only a sample. then use created_at < '2024-04-01 00:00:00' OR created_at < '2024-04-01 23:59:59'

They already tried that. It's not necessary to write 00:00:00 explicitly, it's the default when no time is given.

See the last line of the question, and also the comments.

WHERE created_at >= '2024-04-01' AND created_at < '2024-04-02' does the same job but easier to manage. In some RDBMS you have fractional seconds in dates, then there is rounding issues.
